# Is there any other way of establisiting DB connection in ASP not ASP.net instead of writing in page directly

Tags: asp-classic

Generally we esablish a connecton in `ASP` as follows

```
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open(Server.Mappath("/db/northwind.mdb"))
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
```

Is there any other way of establishing a connection like creating a `COM` object and using that in `ASP` page.

This has been asked in an Interview will you write the connection directly on page or you will get connection from a `COM` so can any one tell if there is any alternative way of establishing a connection..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you could do -

- Write a VB 6 dll that will return a connection object to the page
- Write a VB 6 dll that will return data to the asp page (via a recordset, array or similiar), and abstract
  away any database access code from the asp layer
- Store connection strings in the registry so they are not stored in
  your asp pages

Back in the days of classic asp it was considered 'best practice' by many to put business logic in dlls then call the dll functions from the asp pages. In practice however, this tended to make things more difficult to deploy/debug and could also lead to 'dll hell' scenarios when deploying new versions of the dlls to the server (I think [this episode](http://www.thisdeveloperslife.com/post/1-0-3-problems) of the 'This Developers Life' podcast contains a story about a team that tried to move all it's business logic from a classic asp project into dlls and hit terrible problems). So from a personal view point, when dealing with classic asp, I'd always keep all the logic in the pages themselves.